# How can I add new nodes to a live hbase/hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I run some batch jobs with data inputs that are constantly changing and I'm having problems provisioning capacity. I am using whirl to do the intial setup but once I start, for example, 5 machines I don't know how to add new machines to it while its running. I don't know in advance how complex or how large the data will be so I was wondering if there was a way to add new machines to a cluster and have it take effect right away(or with some delay but don't want to have to bring down the cluster and bring it up with the new nodes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is exact explanation how to add node:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_have_a_new_node_I_want_to_add_to_a_running_Hadoop_cluster.3B_how_do_I_start_services_on_just_one_node.3F

In the same time - I am not sure that already running jobs will take advantages of these nodes since planning where to run each task happens during job start time (as far as I understand). 
I also think that it is more practical to run Task Trackers only on these transient nodes.

Comment: Unstarted tasks may be scheduled on new nodes, but it won't break up existing tasks.  Additionally since none of the new nodes will have data stored locally, the overhead of pushing the data to these nodes for processing might be greater than the cost of processing it where it already lives.

Answer (score 3):

Check the files referred by the below parameters:

- dfs.hosts              => dfs.include
- dfs.hosts.exclude
- mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.filename => mapred.include
- mapreduce.jobtracker.hosts.exclude.filename

You can add the list of hosts to the files  dfs.include and mapred.include and then run

hadoop mradmin -refreshNodes ;

hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes ;

That's all.

BTW, 'mradmin -refreshNodes' facility was added in 0.21

Nikhil